# Не загружается несколько видео на одну страницу. YouTube API

Tags: android, youtube-android-api

В моем приложении есть список ссылок. Если ссылка в списке всего одна - приложение работает отлично, видео воспроизводится отлично и тд. Если ссылок две и более - во всех окнах `YouTubePlayerView` черный экран, только на последнем показана картинка(превьюшка, наверное), кликая по которой видео все равно не работает.
В чем может быть ошибка? Укороченный код `Activity` предоставляю:

```
public class FilmActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity {
    private static final String YOUTUBE_API_KEY = "my_API_key";
    private LinearLayout linLay;
    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);

        linLay = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linlay);

        list.add("https://www.youtube.com/embed/9Vx9YAq4rGY");
        list.add("https://www.youtube.com/embed/AkuwzMsbSng");
        list.add("https://www.youtube.com/embed/rrlvXlH_dLU");

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        for (String s: list){
            final String url=s.substring(30,41);
            YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_video, linLay, false);
            YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener onInitializedListener = new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(url);
                }

                @Override
                public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                    Log.d("logs", "onInitializationFailure");
                }
            };
            youTubePlayerView.initialize(YOUTUBE_API_KEY, onInitializedListener);
            linLay.addView(youTubePlayerView);

            }
        }
}
```

Ну и разметка для видео `item_video.xml`. Ничего сверхъествественного:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/youTubePlayerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

</com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView>
```

Повторю на всякий случай. Когда в списке одна ссылка - все очень ок. Когда две и более - вообще не ок.

Answer (score 0):

То, что вы пытаетесь сделать реализуется в принципе по другому, через такие вещи как ListView как Adapter.

```
public class FilmActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ListView linLay;
private List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);

    linLay = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.linlay);

    list.add("https://www.youtube.com/embed/9Vx9YAq4rGY");
    list.add("https://www.youtube.com/embed/AkuwzMsbSng");
    list.add("https://www.youtube.com/embed/rrlvXlH_dLU");

    youtubeListAdapter = new YoutubeListAdapter(this, R.layout.item_video, list);
    linLay.setAdapter(youtubeListAdapter);
    }
}
```

YoutubeListAdapter

```
public class YoutubeListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

public YoutubeListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
}

public YoutubeListAdapter(Context context, int resource, String[] items) {
    super(context, resource, items);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        youTubePlayerView  = vi.inflate(R.layout.item_video, null);
    }

    String content = getItem(position);

    if (content != null) {
        final String url=content.substring(30,41);
        YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener onInitializedListener = new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                youTubePlayerView.cueVideo(url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                Log.d("logs", "onInitializationFailure");
            }
        };
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(YOUTUBE_API_KEY, onInitializedListener);
    }

    return youTubePlayerView;
}
}
```

Что-то вроде этого вам надо реализовать.

Comment: Нет. То, что я собираюсь реализовать нужно делать через фрагменты просто. Ответ нашел уже.